# Laravel - Group By same day ( Mon , Tue , etcc)

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have the following table:

```
TABLE:schedule

id   day  name 
 -----------------------------
1    Mon   test  
2    Mon   hello
3    Tue   another
4    Tue   here
5    Wed   go
```

I have a Laravel model for this , so I am trying to group day 
here is the result I would like to have as an object:

```
['Mon']-> array[0]='name'=>test,
         array[1]='name'=>hello,
['Tue']-> array[0]='name'=>another,
         array[1]='name'=>here,
```

here is my code in the HomeController:

```
$schedule = DB::table('schedule')
             ->select('*')
             ->groupBy('day')
             ->get();
```

This is not working only showing one day and not grouping them , anyone knows why?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a little bit complicated problem. I think, you are looking something like the following:

```
    $schedules = DB::table('schedule')
                 ->selectRaw('id, day, group_concat(name) as name')
                 ->groupBy('day')
                 ->get();

    $data = array();

    foreach ($schedules as $schedule) {
        $data[$schedule->day][] = explode(",",$schedule->name);
    }

   var_dump($data);
```

output:

```
array (size=3)
  'Mon' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        array (size=12)
          0 => string 'test' (length=4)
          1 => string 'hello' (length=5)
  'Tue' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => string 'another' (length=6)
          1 => string 'here' (length=4)
  'Wed' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string 'go' (length=2)
```

**Edit:**

Do another `group_concat` for extra field.

```
$schedules = DB::table('schedule')
                 ->selectRaw('id, day, group_concat(name) as name, group_concat(city) as city')
                 ->groupBy('day')
                 ->get();

    $data = array();

    foreach ($schedules as $schedule) {
        $data[$schedule->day]['name'] = explode(",",$schedule->name);
        $data[$schedule->day]['city'] = explode(",",$schedule->city);
    }

   var_dump($data);
```

Comment: what about if I have more columns besides name , like : time , address , city how would i do that

Comment: concat by "," is nto a good solution because I could have "," in my name or address or city columns??

Comment: Then you can not do `group by` in your  query. You have do it using php.

Comment: Or you can use different character for `group_concat(name, '$')`. Say `$` sign. and here `explode("$",$schedule->name);`

Comment: so how would you do it with out GroupBy? only php

Comment: get all data from database and do the programming in PHP.

Comment: You mean like loop where day='Mon' and loop where day='Tue' like that